# How to find neighbors of element in matrix in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I need help with a function that's supposed to return all neighbors of element in a matrix, I can't use numpy because it's a project for school.

For example for given matrix:

```
m =  [ 11 12 13
       21 22 23
       31 32 33 ]
```

I need `get_neigbors(x,y)` function that returns all of elements around the element m[x][y].
for example `get_neighbors(1,1)` is supposed to return `[12, 21, 22]`
And please, no one liners!!
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? What went wrong?

Comment: What have you tried?  This is really not that hard.  There are four possible directions: (-1,0), (1,0), (0,-1), (0,-1).  For each one, check that the resulting `x+dx` is still inside the matrix, and return the value.  Since it's homework, we can't provide code until you provide some..

Comment: Your definition of `m` is not valid Python. You say you're not using `numpy` - how is this array defined?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this site can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") and ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions "How do I ask and answer homework questions?") pages for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of dx,dy offsets from the position given and return values for which the relative position is within the matrix's index ranges.

```
def get_neighbours(m,x,y):
    rows, cols = range(len(m)),range(len(m[0]))
    offsets = [(-1,-1),(-1,0),(-1,1),(0,-1),(0,1),(1,-1),(1,0),(1,1)]
    result = []
    for dy,dx in offsets:
        ny, nx = y-1+dy, x-1+dx
        if ny in rows and nx in cols:
            result.append(m[ny][nx])
    return result
```

output:

```
m =  [ [11, 12, 13],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [31, 32, 33] ]

print(get_neighbours(m,1,1)) # [12, 12, 22]
```

*Note that, Python indexes are zero-based but your example assumes that (1,1) is the top-left corner, so I subtracted 1 from the parameter values to get actual indexes in the matrix. You also need to pass the matrix as parameter to the function in order to access its content.*